# Count unique and convert it to percentages in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am developing React app which contains data visualisation. I'll need to manipulate data with javascript library or vanilla javascript. This is what JSON data looks like:

```
 [
  {
    "respondent": "John",
    "question 1": 1,
    "question 2": 2,
    "question 3": 7
  },
  {
    "respondent": "Steve",
    "question 1": 3,
    "question 2": 4,
    "question 3": 2
  },
  {
    "respondent": "Jack",
    "question 1": 5,
    "question 2": 3,
    "question 3": 6
  },
  {
    "respondent": "Patricia",
    "question 1": 4,
    "question 2": 3,
    "question 3": 4
  },
  {
    "respondent": "Matt",
    "question 1": 6,
    "question 2": 2,
    "question 3": 1
  }
]
```

Each key is the question text. The value represent poll answer between 1 and 7.

In order to visualise it, it needs to look something like this:

```
const answers = [
  {"question":"question 1", "answer":"1", "percent":0.09},
  {"question":"question 1", "answer":"2", "percent":0.27},
  {"question":"question 1", "answer":"3", "percent":0.59}
  ...
  {"question":"question 3", "answer":"5", "percent":0.09},
  {"question":"question 3", "answer":"6", "percent":0.27},
  {"question":"question 3", "answer":"7", "percent":0.59}
]
```

So I'll need to count unique values in each question and convert it to percentages. 100% = all the answers within the same question

How would you make this data manipulation? Here is larger dataset to play around with: https://pastebin.com/ZuyV8w6Z

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with.

```
  const surveyData = [...]

  let cleanSurveyData = [];

  //Get unique questions
  const questions = _.chain(surveyData).map(_.keys).flatten().uniq().value();

  //Iterate over each question
  questions.forEach(function(questionTitle) {

    //Grab data only containing selected question title
    let mapSelectedData = _.map(surveyData, questionTitle)

    //Count how many answers total
    let answersTotal = mapSelectedData.length;

    //Count how many times each number appears in the answer
    mapSelectedData = _.countBy(mapSelectedData)

    //possible answers are 1 to 7
    const answerRange = _.range(1,8)

    //iterate over possible answers
    answerRange.forEach(function(selectedNumber) {
        let element = {};
        element.question = questionTitle;
        element.answerNumber = selectedNumber;

        //Get value from selectedNumber
        let numVal = _(mapSelectedData).result(selectedNumber);

        element.count = (isNaN(numVal) ? 0 : numVal)

        element.pct = element.count / answersTotal;

        cleanSurveyData.push(element);
    })

    console.log(cleanSurveyData)
```